# Docker : cannot access internet from container

Tags: networking, centos, proxy, centos-6, docker

I am running CentOS 6.6 behind a corporate proxy. I've installed docker, and I had to make some modifications in order for the daemon to access the Docker Hub through the proxy. This part is working fine.

```
# /etc/sysconfig/docker
HTTP_PROXY='http://domain\username:password@proxy:port'
HTTPS_PROXY='https://domain\username:password@proxy:port'
export HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY
```

My problem is that my containers seems like they can't access the internet (apt-get update times out, can't get the user-guide web app to work, ...).

I have `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`on both host and containers.

I've tried multiple things I've found with a google research, but without success :

- adding option `-p :80` in order to redirect HTTP requests through the host
- adding option `--net=host`
- adding `--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4` (I'm not even able to ping the dns servers when doing this)
- setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables in the containers

If you need me to post some output I'll be glad to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem, and it wasn't at all related to Docker. It was just a proxy problem.

I was testing by running an ubuntu:14.10 container, and by running `apt-get update`, which wasn't working.

The solution was to edit the /etc/apt/apt.conf file in the container to add the proxy information. After that, `apt-get update` was working like a charm.

Comment: Thank you this saved me a load of trouble. For others: the proxies need to be formatted like in this answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/342180/313830